# How stop overwrite but adds a number beside the name

Tags: batch-file

How to stop overwriting but add a new number beside the name.

I tried to make this code, but it didn't work.

```
set overwrite=0
set newoverwrite=0
:loop
if (%textfile.txt%==EXIST) goto fix
:fix
set /a newoverwrite=%overwrite%+1
if (%textfile%newoverwrite%.txt%==EXIST) goto fix
echo hello > textfile%newoverwrite%.txt
echo skipped!
pause > nul
```

It is a bit sloppy because I have tested it many times.

Does anyone know how? Or fix my code?

Comment: @FZs, it's the other way round: `!textfile%newoverwrite%.txt!`. Nevertheless, I think it should simply be `textfile%neeoverwrite%.txt` (refer to the first `echo` line)…

Comment: Correct @aschipfl, additionally, `set /a newoverwrite=%overwrite%+1` will always become `1` because `overwrite` is always `0`

Comment: @aschipfl You're right! My batch skills are definitely getting rusty...

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you want to create files by just incrementing numbers to it.

```
@echo off & set cnt=0
:loop
type "textfile%cnt%.txt">nul 2>&1 && echo skipped textfile%cnt%.txt || (echo hello)>"textfile%cnt%.txt"
set /a cnt+=1
pause
goto :loop
```

I am not sure though if you are aware that this will create files in a permanent loop until you interrupt the process. so **Do Not** remove the `pause` from the script.

To explain what it does. We test the file for existance by attemtping to `type` the file. If the file does exist, `type` is successful and generates `errorlevel` of 0. This is where the `&&` conditional operators come into play. If the errorlevel is `0` then it will execute the command after `&&` which is to echo `Skipped..`. However, should the file not exist will it will generate `errorlevel` of `1` and skip the `&&` operator where the code after `||` will be executed.